# Не могу получить куки из post-запроса посредством HttpClient

Tags: java, cookie, httpclient

Привет! 
После успешной программной авторизации на сайте необходимо перейти на другую страницу этого сайта, при этом не разлогинившись. Как я понимаю, нужно авторизоваться, получить куки, сохранить их для следующего запроса.
Попытка получить куки из первого запроса оканчивается неудачей: "No cookies".
В чём может быть проблема?
Делаю следующим образом:

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       try {

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();     
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpClient instance = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://url");
        HttpResponse httppost = instance.execute(httpost);

        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "myid"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userpass", "mypass"));

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = instance.execute(httpost, responseHandler);

         List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No cookies");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
               }
        }

 //Второй post-запрос
/*       HttpClient instance2 = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
         HttpPost httpost2 = new HttpPost("http://url2");    
         httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
         HttpResponse httppost2 = instance.execute(httpost2);
         ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler2 = new BasicResponseHandler();
         String responseBody2 = instance2.execute(httpost2, responseHandler2);
         System.out.println(responseBody2);
         System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");*/

    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        System.out.println("Это конец.");
    }
}
}
```

Все получается если сделать так, как ниже указал PhoEn-X, спасибо!
Далее, я пытаюсь установить полученные куки, создаю новый запрос, но в ответ получаю, что я не авторизованный пользователь. Каким образом сделать второй запрос как уже авторизованный пользователь?
Возможно, я делаю глупость, но делаю вот так:

```
                BasicClientCookie cookie1 = new BasicClientCookie("mykey", cookie.getValue());
                cookie1.setDomain("domain");
                cookie1.setPath("/");
                cookieStore.addCookie(cookie1);
                HttpClient instance2 = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
                HttpPost httpost2 = new HttpPost("http://url2");
                HttpResponse response2 = instance2.execute(httpost2, httpContext);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler2 = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody2 = instance2.execute(httpost2, responseHandler2);
                System.out.println(responseBody2);
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                System.out.println(response2);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://url");
CookieStore cookieStore;
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "myid"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userpass", "mypass"));
    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
    cookieStore = ((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore();
    //Выведем в консоль имена cookie с их значениями
    List<Cookie> cookieList = cookieStore.getCookies();
    if(!cookieList.isEmpty()) {
        for(Cookie cookie : cookieList) {
            System.out.println(cookie.getName() + " = " +  cookie.getValue());
        }
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//Отправим второй запрос
HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost("http://url2");
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Параметр1", "Значение1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Параметр2", "Значение2"));
    httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
    ((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).setCookieStore(cookieStore);
    //Бывает и так, что надо прикреплять заголовки к запросу (FireBug поможет увидеть, какие именно нужны), например:
    httppost2.addHeader("Host", "site.ru");
    httppost2.addHeader("Referer", "http://site.ru/");
    //Заголовки прикрепили
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost2, localContext);
    //И выведем в консоль, что нам пришло в ответе
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    System.out.println(inputStreamToString(is));
    is.close();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Метод для считывания ответа сервера из входного потока + преобразование в строку
private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String s = "";
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            s += line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Таким образом работает.
Сейчас сталкиваюсь с новой проблемой, при создании второго запроса я не воспринимаюсь как авторизованный пользователь
Подробнее описано выше в дополнении к первому посту

Comment: я для таких вещей храню cookie в SharedPreferences. Правильно ли я поступаю - без понятия) Сейчас допишу код, чтобы выполнялся и второй запрос)) Да, и в воспользуйтесь дополнением FireBug для браузера Mozilla FireFox (если вы, конечно, уже не используете), чтобы смотреть что у вас отправляется, с какими параметрами и какими заголовками))